Creation inner fragments in onCreateView of another fragment
I have a fragment containing a table (scrollable list). Each row of this table is a fragment too (subfragment). All these subfragments are created in the onCreateView method of the root fragment and these subfragments do not have default (without arguments) constructors. I supposed that they do not need default constructors because there are no layouts with these subfragments and Android must call firstly the onCreatView method and they all will be recreated. But it appeared that sometimes Android tries to call default constructors for them.
I can create for them default constructors and provide them with underlaying global data structures. But if Android creates all these subfragments by itself and then it calls the onCreateView of the root fragment it may results in having two copies of all subfragments in the list! So I have some questons:

Is it a bad practice to create some views or fragments in onCreateView and I am allowed only to call findViewById here? Should I do this in onCreate or in the root fragment constructor?
Does Android call onCreate or onCreateView in the situation when it recreates the page this way?
Thanks for any answer!

P.S. I solved the problem and have found out how this works. If we have a fragment with some subfragments and rotate the screen (or probably do something else making Android recreate the Activity) the callback sequence is:

onSaveInstanseState of each descendant
onAttach of each descendant
onCreateView of parent
onCreateView and then onViewStateRestored of each descendant
onStart of parent

Surely this list is incomplete and contains only callabcks I put breakpoints in. The Activity recreation must be between points 1 and 2.
Also if You add some subfragments on the fragmet startup (I do it in onStart callback) You have to check if this subfragment already exists. Otherwise You will have all your subfragmets duplicated after screen rotation.

Fragments should not have constructor arguments. If you need to provide them correct pattern is to create a static newInstance(arg1, arg2, ....) method that encapsulates them in a Bundle and use it to setArguments(Bundle) on a fresh instance. That way arguments are preserved by FragmentManager.

Why are the table rows different fragments? Do they need lifecycle independent from the host fragment or do you just need separate view/layouts?

"But it appeared that sometimes Android tries to call default constructors for them" -- Android will automatically recreate the fragments on a configuration change, and Android will use the zero-argument constructor for that. "Each row of this table is a fragment too" -- IMHO, that is a very strange implementation.

In this table each row has its own logic and the logic of different rows differs. So I had a choice to create some custom compound views of several types or use sub-fragments instead. The last variant seemed to be more simple.  If Android recreates all my subfragments does it mean that it also added their views into the table? I am afraid that if it does it and then calls my onCreateView of the root fragment which also creates and adds new copies of these subfragments I could have each subfragment twice there
